# androidのView.animationでInterpolatorをドロップダウンリストから種類を選択できるようにしたい

Tags: android

全部で９つあるInterpolatorをSpinnerに追加しました。
そこから選択されたアイテムに応じてsetInterpolatorを書くボタンを押す毎に変更できるようにしたい
例を示すと、AnticipateInterpolatorをSpinnerで選択し移動ボタンをタップすると、通常の移動のアニメーションにAnticipateInterpolatorが追加され表示される
のようにしたいです
[image: 各エフェクト毎にInterpolatorを設定したい]
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

今考えているのはif文でspinnerのアイテムを判断し、１つずつ

```
if(spinnerから取得した値==OvershootInterpolator){
    trans.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator());
else if(spinnerから取得した値==AnticipateInterpolator){
    trans.setInterpolator(new AnticipateInterpolator());
```

書いていくことしか思いつかないのですが、そうすると数が増えてくると困難です
いい方法がありましたら、教えてください

Answer (score 1):

`Map`に保持するのがいいと思います。

単に`Map<String, Interpolator>`を用意すればいいのですが、それでは無駄な`Interpolator`を生成しますし、芸もないのでリフレクションを使ってみます。

特定のバージョンのSDKにしかないものやリソース定義された`Animation`については考慮していないですが、

```
final static Map<String, Class<? extends Interpolator>> easingMap;
static {
    Map<String, Class<? extends Interpolator>> tmpMap = new HashMap<>();
    tmpMap.put("OvershootInterpolator", android.view.animation.OvershootInterpolator.class);
    easingMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(tmpMap);
}
```

このような`Map`を定義しておき、

```
Animation anim = null;
try {
    anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 10, 300, 20);
    anim.setDuration(500);
    anim.setInterpolator(easingMap.get("OvershootInterpolator").getConstructor().newInstance());
} catch (Exception e) {
    // InstantiationException、IllegalAccessException、InvocationTargetException、
    // NoSuchMethodExceptionをハンドリングする必要がありますが、例示なのでポケモン例外処理です。
    e.printStackTrace();
}

if(anim != null) {
    imageView.startAnimation(anim);
}
```

`getConstructor().newInstance()`で動的に`Interpolator`を生成するという方法が取れます。